# Restrict visibility of database entries for some users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

**The Problem**
I am trying to create a website, where users can post posts and then their friends can see these posts. Similar to facebook, twitter etc.
I got to the point where users can be friends and they can post things. However, I am stuck restricting the shown posts to just the user's friends' posts. At the moment every user can see every post.
I am using PDO in a MVC architecture.

**The database structure**

```
TABLE `friends` (
    `friendship_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`friendship_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_one) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_two) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

```
TABLE `posts` (
 `post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_text` text NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**The Model**

```
    /**
     * Get all posts from the suer's friends
     * @return array an array with several objects (the posts)
     */
    public static function getAllPosts()
    {   
        $my_id = Session::get('user_id');

        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        // get all of the user's friends
        $friends = $database->prepare("
                                    SELECT user_one FROM friends WHERE user_two = '$my_id';
                                    SELECT user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one = '$my_id';
                                    ");

        $query = $database->prepare("SELECT post_text FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$my_id' OR user_id = '$friends'");
        $query->execute(array());

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

**The Controller**

```
    /**
     * Gets all posts (of the user and his friends).
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->View->render('post/index', array(
            'posts' => PostModel::getAllPosts()
        ));
    }
```

**The View**

```
       <?php if ($this->posts) { ?>
            <?php foreach($this->posts as $key => $value) { ?>
                <p><?= htmlentities($value->post_text); ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

**The Error Message**

> Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in **PostModel.php**

**The Goal**
Just show posts of myself and my friends. Do not show posts of users, I am not friends with.

**UPDATE**
**The updated Model** (thank you for the helpful comments!)

```
/**    
 * Get all posts from the suer's friends
 * @return array an array with several objects (the posts)
 */
public static function getAllPosts()
{   
    $my_id = Session::get('user_id');

    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    // get all of the user's friends
    $friendsQuery = $database->prepare("
                                SELECT user_one FROM friends WHERE user_two = '$my_id';
                                SELECT user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one = '$my_id';
                                ");

    $friendsQuery->execute();
    $friends = $friendsQuery->fetchAll();

    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT post_text FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$my_id' OR user_id = '$friends'");
    $query->execute(array());

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

**The new Error Message**

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot
>   execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.

Comment: whats the use of preparing statements if you're just gonna inject direct variables on the string

Comment: I do not know what that 'inject direct variables on the string' means but I was told that preparing statements like this would be good practice, so I do that for each and every query.

Comment: Which CMS or mvc architecture platform you are using.. ?

Comment: I am not using any CMS I built my application onto this https://github.com/panique/huge

Comment: You're just injecting the `$friends` variable, which contains a `PDOStatement` in to another query with out actually fetching the data first. You need to execute that query (as you do for the other one) and get the friends data.

Comment: you bind those variables, not directly using your variables to be interpolated in that query string. heres a tutorial that you could consult in using prepared statements properly http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers and what value are you expecting with `$friends` anyway?

Comment: @Bulk Thank you so much!! I updated my question! Could you help me out with this new error message as well?

Comment: @Ghost Thank you so much!! I updated my question! Could you help me out with this new error message as well?

Comment: @kringeltorte just like bulk said, execute the first preparation above then fetch the values, then use that fetch value form the first one on the second preparation then execute also